# VS Code Include Errors Detected. "cannot open source file 'main.h' "

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

This questions might look similar to other questions but nothing I've tried has worked. I'm using a library called PROS for Vex robotics. I get the include detected error where it can't find the `main.h` file located in the workspace folder. I checked the `c_cpp_properties.json` to check if the folder was somehow not included.

Additionally, I tried re-installing VS code, updating the PROS library, making a new project. Nothing seems to be working, maybe I'm just overlooking a simple problem.

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/7701x_code/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_commands.json",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Here's the [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAeDZ.png) and error output:

[image: error output]

Comment: So there's a file /Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/7701x_code/src/auton_functions.cpp that includes a file called main.h and you are expecting it to find that in your workspace folder? Is that correct, because it seems a little weird to me. Maybe you should describe where all the files you have are.

Comment: Ok, I updated the summary and added an image of how the folders are set up. The workspace folder should be 7701x_code.

Comment: So your workspace folder is `/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/7701x_code` or is it 7701x_code in some other location? Sorry to keep on at this but the precise details matter.

Comment: Yeah ```/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/7701x_code``` is the workspace folder

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the answer. I wonder if it's an Intellisense caching issue, try the instructions here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-recreate-the-intellisense-database

Comment: I reinstalled VScode and still have the same problem. I don't know what to do exactly with the intellisense cache.